# AWS IAM User unable to create Elastic Beanstalk environment. Missing permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, elastic-beanstalk, amazon-iam

Permissions option is missing from user sub-accounts. How do I enable it for sub accounts? In the screenshot below I am logged in on the main account.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The "Permissions" step will only show up if the user that's trying to create the new environment has permissions to list IAM roles (`iam:ListRoles`). Such a policy could look like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:ListRoles"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Remember that the user also needs permission to pass the role to the instances created in the environment (`iam:PassRole`). It's also a good idea to [restrict](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2.html#roles-usingrole-ec2instance-passrole) which roles the user should be allowed to pass.